# codeigniter can't upload picture to folder

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I need help to upload picture in folder. Here's the thing, I have tested before and it worked. After a while I test this again and boom it doesn't work. I really can't think straight here, please help!

my view :

```
<?php 
        echo form_open_multipart("adminFolder/admin/insert_picture");

        echo form_upload("userfile", "Gambar Picture");

        echo form_submit("input_picture", "Input now !!!");

        ?>
```

my controller :

```
public function insert_picture(){
        $this->model_get->doUpload();
    }
```

my model :

```
function doUpload(){
        $path = './assets/images/';
        chmod($path, 0777);

        $config['upload_path'] = $path; 
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'; 
        $config['max_size'] = '6000'; 
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768'; 
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library("upload", $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            redirect("adminFolder/admin/insertPicture");
        }else{

            redirect("adminFolder/admin/adminPic");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should require to pass filename in do_upload :

So your code of model will be :

```
  if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        redirect("adminFolder/admin/insertPicture");
    }else{

        redirect("adminFolder/admin/adminPic");
    }
```

And this will work !! Please try

Comment: i've tried, still the same, funny thing is i copy the exact code to another empty project and it worked, but doesn' work on my primary project, dont know what to say anymore

Comment: Please write echo $this->upload->display_errors(); exit;
   inside  if code and before redirect line and it will echo error in uploading

Answer (score 1):

use in view:

input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="userfile" name="userfile"

**Controller**
In your controller method add this line
 $this->gallery_model->do_upload($data);

**Create One model class "gallery_model"**

```
var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;

function Gallery_model() {
    parent::__construct(); 

    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'images/';

}

function do_upload() {

    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => 2000
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ration' => true,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 100
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

}

function get_images() {

    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path);
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $images []= array (
            'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . $file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'thumbs/' . $file
        );
    }

    return $images;
}
```

If you need Multiple Image Upload I can paste the Code for that also.!!